# Интеллектуальный поиск по текст

Tags: база-данных, firebase, поиск, nosql

Мне нужно организовать поиск по базе, но не просто! Например, в базе содержится запись "больашя рыжая кошка", а в поисковых запросах, для выдачи результата с этой записью, можно было бы ввести, например:

-рыжие

-рыжий

-большие кошки

и тп и тд

То есть что бы искал не грубое совпадение, а по вариациям слова/слов

Как это можно реализовать?

Платформы, языки, структура БД, сервисы для реализации значения не имеют (конечно, хорошо бы все это организовать средствами Firebase).
А вообще просто понять куда копать ))
Спасибо!

Comment: Elasticsearch вроде умеет из готового

Comment: Остановился на Sphinx